# Meta box or shortcode help

Tags: plugins, shortcode

Im trying to code a meta-box or plug-in that would allow me to change one specific string of text within the title of page and content.  For example: "Places to park in [city].  Anywhere [city] is displayed, I would like to change it using a meta-box within the page editor.

Novice coder here, not having any luck finding a plugin to do so.

TIA

Answer (score 0):

First create the meta box with a simple input value to insert the text you want. [Here is a good example.](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/10/create-custom-post-meta-boxes-wordpress/)

Then you take the input from the meta box and create a function to store it as a shortcode. Check out the [Shortcode API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API) to enable the shortcode. Something like this should do the trick:

```
function new_title( $atts ) {
    if (!isset ($_POST['your_meta_input'])) {
        return;
    }

     else {
        return $_POST['your_meta_input'];
     }
 }

add_shortcode( 'city', 'new_title');
```

Answer (score 0):

You should also keep in mind that the Page or Post title not only effects the title as displayed on the page, but also the  attribute defined in the header.

I would be more inclined to write a function using the filters provided by WordPress:

```
add_filter( 'the_title', 'your_function_name', 10, 2 );
```

and

```
add_filter( 'wp_title', 'your_function_name', 10, 2 );
```

From here you could use the shortcode code to update the correct value or a simple replace string command.